# Where and how to use NULLIF(X,Y) function of SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

I know that NULLIF(X,Y) function of SQLITE work equivalent to:

```
CASE
    WHEN
        X = Y
    THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        X
END
```

and IFNULL(X,Y) function work equivalent to:

```
CASE
    WHEN
        X IS NULL
    THEN
        Y
    ELSE
        X
END
```

IFNULL(X,Y) function of SQLITE is used for replacing the NULL values of X to the Y but I can't understand the use of NULLIF(X,Y) function of SQLITE.
Please explain with examples, so it is more useful.

Comment: Did you Google it? I found good uses for such function this way.

Comment: Yes bro the question is the result of google search. I found only theory about it on google so i asked with example so I can understand its realtime use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The IFNULL function is used when the database contains NULL values, but you want to handle those values as something else; for example:

```
SELECT Name, IFNULL(Age, 'unknown') AS Age FROM People
```

The NULLIF function is used when the database contains special values that are *not* NULL, but that you want to handle as NULL.
This is useful especially for aggregate functions. For example, to get the number of employees that get bonuses, use:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(Bonus, 0)) FROM Employees
```

This is the same as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees WHERE Bonus != 0
```

In practice, NULLIF is not used as often as IFNULL.

Comment: Also useful for converting empty strings into NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I use **NULLIF()** when **UPDAT**ing or **INSERT**ing rows containing **NULL**able fieds.

Basically with PHP :

```
$value1 = 'foo';
$value2 = '';

$sql = 'INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) '
     . "VALUES(NULLIF('$value1', ''), NULLIF('$value2', ''))";

// => INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) VALUES(NULLIF('foo', ''), NULLIF('', ''))
// => INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) VALUES('foo', NULL)
```

It saves me doing things like :

```
$value1forSQL = ($value1 === '' || $value1 === NULL) ? 'NULL' : "'$value1'";
...
$sql = ...
     . "VALUES($value1forSQL, ...)";
```